# admin.attributes.isAdmin is assigned value. while guest.attributes.isAdmin is assigned nothing . Please let me understand it

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand this code snipped:

```
var User = function() {};

User.prototype.attributes = {
  isAdmin: false
};

var admin = new User("Sam"),
  guest = new User("Bob");

admin.attributes.isAdmin = true;

alert(admin.attributes.isAdmin);
alert(guest.attributes.isAdmin);
```

its output will be true (twice)

Kindly help me out in understanding the concept. Any help is mush appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use a copy of `attributes`, because by addressing `attributes`, you overwrite the value for all instances.

```js
var User = function() {
        this.attributes = Object.assign({}, this.attributes);
    };

User.prototype.attributes = { isAdmin: false };

var admin = new User("Sam"), 
    guest = new User("Bob");

admin.attributes.isAdmin = true;

console.log(admin.attributes.isAdmin); 
console.log(guest.attributes.isAdmin);
```

Javascript takes a property and looks if it exits. If not, it looks in the prototype chain if the property exist here. If it exist, it take this value.

Same goes for assigning a value.

Fo a more detailed view, you may vistit [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: thank you for your quick response but what I am confused about is admin.attributes.isAdmin is true. admin and guest have inherited from user so. when guest.attributes.isAdmin is not set to any value. why it is not false

Answer (score 0):

In JS objects are passed by reference. In your example`admin` and `guest` store references to the same object `attributes`. You could clone the object (create a copy of it's values) or store the `isAdmin` property in the `prototype`.